# applescript do shell script, xcode build fail to find project

Tags: shell, applescript, xcodebuild

I'm trying to play with AppleScript to compile all my Xcode projects.
I'm using the command `do shell script` to call Xcode like this :

```
try
    do shell script "xcodebuild -project /Path/MyProject.xcodeproj -nodistribute -activetarget -sdk macosx10.5  -configuration Release build"
    on error errMsg
    TraceError(errMsg)
    return
end try
```

But Xcode always complains it can't find the project.

If I call the same command directly in the terminal, it works fine.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using an absolute path or relative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can't find the project it's probably because there are some spaces or something in the path which makes it unrecognizable in the form you have it. You normally would "quote" a path to account for these types of things. In applescript we can use the "quoted form of" command to solve this problem. Give the following a try and see if it helps.

```
set projectPath to "/Path/MyProject.xcodeproj"
do shell script "xcodebuild -project " & quoted form of projectPath & " -nodistribute -activetarget -sdk macosx10.5  -configuration Release build"
```